# Addition and Multiplication of items in a single line with shell script

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I currently have a variable `$var1' that contains the following:

```
4 -38 2 -42 1 -43 10 -44 1 -45 6 -46 1 -48 1 -49
```

I want to add 50 and then multiply by 2 for every second number. That is,

`(-38 + 50) * 2 = 24`

`(-42 + 50) * 2 = 16`

I would then want to replace `-38` with `24` and `-42` with `16`. How should I go about doing this?

Would you do this with `awk`? If so, how do you cycle through the each item in a single line? I see `awk` can loop through rows but haven't seen an example of looping through items on a line.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ echo "$var1" | awk '{for (i=2;i<=NF;i+=2) $i=($i+50)*2}1'
4 24 2 16 1 14 10 12 1 10 6 8 1 4 1 2
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
echo $var | awk -F" " '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if(i%2 == 0) printf "%d ",( $i + 50 ) * 2 ; else printf "%d ",$i  }'
```